# SQL Server Authentication in Silverlight/RIA-Services app

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, asp.net-membership, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am creating a new Silverlight 4 business application using RIA services.  This will be using a SQL-Server 2005 DB.  There is no AD setup so I am required to use SQL Server Authentication.  The details that the user uses to login to the system will be used to hit the SQL Server.

E.g., if username="TestUser" and password="Password" is entered in the login screen of the application, these will be the credentials that will be used to access the DB.

I am wondering what the best way to do this will be?  At this point the method of accessing the DB is undecided (EF or 'traditional' ADO.NET using stored procs).

I think current applications take the username and password entered into the login screen, use them to build a connection string and see if they can hit the DB using this, if it works they're in, if not they're declined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with EF and changing the AuthenticationServices Login() method to attempt to hit the database with the required username and password.

I wrote a blog post about how I [Dynamically changed connection string for EF](http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2010/06/abstract-class-to-dynamically-alter-entityframework-domain-service-connection/)